# Payment processes, but order doesn't show up in back-end?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

When somebody checks out on our store (options are PayPal or Credit Card) they get a receipt from the gateway and a more detailed invoice from Magento. We're copied on both.

About a month ago, in the midst of some other perfectly normal orders, we got a PayPal receipt for an order that didn't appear in Magento. We assumed this was a clever con, but after logging into PayPal, the transaction was in there - and the receipt included the line items, passed over from Magento. It just didn't exist anywhere in the Magento back-end.

This seemed odd but it only happened once, so we moved on with our lives and adjusted the stock levels manually.

Today, the same thing has happened - but this time the customer has checked out using CC, and the merchant gateway receipt doesn't include the order line items. We can see the receipt mailed out to the customer from our gateway, we can see the money in our account, but there's no trace of it in Magento - which means we don't know what they actually bought.

We can just email them and ask, but it's a pretty bad look. Any guesses what's happening here? Have you ever witnessed similar behaviour, or is there something I can do to debug?

This time tomorrow I'll be able to check if it has tracked into Google Analytics, which will tell me if the customer made it to the "order confirmed" screen on our site. When it was just PayPal I thought maybe they hadn't returned to the site (although I think Magento creates the order when you hit submit, not after you return from PayPal). The CC gateway is integrated into the checkout flow, so they would never have even left the site.

Answer (score 0):

Creating order depends on the Payment Method, so make sure the order is created once the Submit Order button in checkout page is hit (By creating a test order).

If the order is created once the Submit Order button is hit then check for the missing order in the database table `sales_flat_order` if your Magento version is 1.x or check `sales_order` if your Magento version is 2.x (By searching the `customer_id`, `created_at`, etc).

Because sometimes the orders get created in `sales_flat_order` / `sales_order` but not in `sales_flat_order_grid` / `sales_order_grid` due to which you were not able to find the orders in Magento admin.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after some hours debug and check files debug.log, exception.log, payment.log, I found the issue is

```
Numeric value out of range: 167 Out of range value for column 'sequence_value' at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `sequence_invoice_1` () VALUES ()
```

Then I go to table sequence_invoice_1 and have changed the type of "sequence_value" from int(10) to bigint(20). Now, it works fine.

Our customer has a lot of order migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2. That is an issue.